# Combining two arrays and send them to Highcharts

Tags: javascript, php, highcharts

I am trying to adapt the code obtained on the web for my use. I have a lot of experience in C, C++ and Python, but almost none in PHP, so I do not know where to start, because I don't fully understand code and PHP concepts.

So the idea is that the program reads data from the SQL table, `etime` is epoch time (integer) and `value` are float values (strings).  Then those data are plotted using Highcharts, where in the original code `etime` is category.

PHP part:

```
$etime = json_encode(array_reverse(array_column($sensor_data, 'etime')), JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
$value = json_encode(array_reverse(array_column($sensor_data, 'value')), JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);

var etime = <?php echo $etime; ?>;
var value = <?php echo $value; ?>;
```

Javascript (?) part:

```
var chartT = new Highcharts.Chart({
  series: [{
    data: value
  }],
  xAxis: { 
    categories: etime
  }
});
```

I would like to adapt this code so that `etime` is `datetime` instead of category.  As far as I understand from the web, I should combine arrays `$etime` and `$value` into an array of pairs `[$etime, $value]` and change `categories: etime` to `type: 'datetime'`.  However, I do not know how to do that.

As an example `$etime = [0,1,2]` and `$value = [3,4,5]`, and I need `[[0,3],[1,4],[2,5]]`.

Can you please help me with this?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? Is this a JS problem or a PHP problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PHP can combine the data content like this.
You need to multiply the time by 1000 to get the MS that JS/HighChart expects

```
// Assuming $sensor_data is already populated with your data
$combined_data = array();
foreach ($sensor_data as $data) {
    $etime_millisec = intval($data['etime']) * 1000; // Convert to milliseconds
    $value = floatval($data['value']); // Ensure value is a float
    $combined_data[] = array($etime_millisec, $value);
}

$combined_data_json = json_encode(array_reverse($combined_data), JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
```

Then in the HighChart part you can change to datetime

```
var chartData = <?php echo $combined_data_json; ?>;

var chartT = new Highcharts.Chart({
    series: [{
        data: chartData
    }],
    xAxis: { 
        type: 'datetime' // Changed from 'categories' to 'datetime'
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, it works.  I correctly predicted the Highcharts/Javascript part, but I just didn't know how to syntactically correctly join two arrays.  And I did not know about the 1000 factor.